# Android: Tips on running an activity without a background while running an application and service

Tags: java, android

Its pretty hard to explain what I'm trying to do and I need tips in achieving this because I'm a noob. Please bear with me.

I have a code that launches the downloaded application and its working perfectly. But I also want to launch a form that I've created with an image at the same time overlapping the application that I've run. I just want to know if this is possible and what I'm doing is possible.

I've been searching for a couple of codes in the internet and found the Service. I"m not sure if what I'm going to do is right but the form that I will create with an image implements service because they say that I can create a form in the Service and the Service runs the codes in the "public void run()" unless the service have been stopped.

So that's my problem. I only need tips on how to do this. I don't need the codes because I want to learn the codes for myself and android has a documentation for it. I only need to know what are the things that I needed to study in order to achieve this like for example the "Service" component or do I need the "Fragment" component. And that's it. Thanks :)

Comment: How do you mean: launch a form at the same time?
If you have an application that launches another application you can call your form from the "parent" application. Can you elaborate what you want to do there?

Comment: I wanted to create a GameManager that launches games. The reason why I wanted to put an image that overlapses the game is to put advertisement. That's what I'm trying to do for my project.